# PTIJ: Forfeit your own Olam Haba?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

They say if you embarrass someone, you lose your chelek in Olam Haba. So if you try to go for a high note during leining and have a voice crack and people make fun of you and thus you caused your own embarrassment, do you lose your portion in Olam Haba?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: But the person who one embarrassed gets it, so it comes right back to the guy

Comment: @אילפא where does it say that?

Comment: This sounds like a legit question. Is one allowed to embarrass oneself, and what are the consequences?

Comment: @RabbiKaii Surely one is allowed to embarrass oneself in a good cause. They say he was called Yechezkel ben Buzi, because his father embarrassed himself for the sake of the Torah.

Comment: @MichoelR [Déjà vu](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/133509/31534)

Answer (score 3):

The first time this happens, it is so embarrassing that it acts as both a deterrent and a forgiveness in the same stroke. As it says in [Yechezkel 16:63](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.16.63?lang=bi):

> 'לְמַ֤עַן תִּזְכְּרִי֙ וָבֹ֔שְׁתְּ וְלֹ֨א יִֽהְיֶה־לָּ֥ךְ עוֹד֙ פִּתְח֣וֹן פֶּ֔ה מִפְּנֵ֖י כְּלִמָּתֵ֑ךְ בְּכַפְּרִי־לָךְ֙ לְכׇל־אֲשֶׁ֣ר עָשִׂ֔ית נְאֻ֖ם אֲדֹנָ֥י ה
>
> Thus you shall remember and feel shame, and you shall be too abashed to open your mouth again, when I have forgiven you for all that you did—declares the Sovereign GOD.

Comment: Can someone please explain why an answer that brings a source to answer some Purim Torah is downvoted. I get it, if people do not find it funny but why the downvote?

Comment: how do you add btw the big bold “Purim Torah” words to a post I couldn’t figure it out

Comment: Seriously!!! :-)

Comment: @CuriousYid you can always go to a question that has it, hit "edit" and see the coding and then copy and paste it into your question.